# Spacetime curvature effect on chemistry

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, physical-chemistry, estimation

Do current chemistry / astrophysics / stellar chemistry calculations include the effects of the curvature of spacetime on chemical reactions?

For example, the heat transfer from a point closer to the center of the Sun would be influenced by the gravity well, regarding relativistic time distortion, as the energy moves up the well.

Comment: Do you have reason to suspect that they need such corrections?

Comment: I have no empirical or observational reason to suggest that they need correction, this just seems like a logical continuation of relativity, so I was curious if this has been integrated into our understanding of large-mass "chemistry". As @michael-seifert suggests, this phenomenon does have a name associated with it - post-Newtonian effects of general relativity.

Comment: We're often asked "Does Advanced Theory play a role in X?" questions that are, in my opinion very poor questions. I posted my comment to get you to actually *explain* your reasoning (preferably *not* post-hoc as you have now argued) for why you think it would matter, which would make a better question.

Answer (score 5):

What you're talking about are the so-called *post-Newtonian* effects of general relativity:  those effects of gravity that are not predicted by Newtonian gravity.  As you might be aware, general relativity has Newtonian gravity as a limit:  if a particle's velocity is small compared to the speed of light, and the sources of gravity are not moving quickly either, then the predictions of Newtonian gravity are recovered to a very good approximation.

Now, when I say "a very good approximation", I mean that there are very small corrections that do exist to the Newtonian predictions.  These corrections are governed by two dimensionless parameters:

- The speed of the particles moving in the potential, divided by $c$;  and
- The Newtonian gravitational potential divided by $c^2$.

Any corrections to the effects of Newtonian gravity will generally be on the order of one of these two parameters.  So, for example, in the center of the Sun the gravitational potential is on the order of
$$
\Phi \propto \frac{G M_\odot}{r_\odot} \approx 6 \times 10^{7} \, \text{J/kg},
$$
which means any corrections due to general relativity will be on the order of 
$$
\Phi/c^2 \approx 7 \times 10^{-10}.
$$
Similarly, the thermal velocities of the hydrogen nuclei in the center of the Sun ($T \approx 15 \times 10^6$ K) will be on the order of
$$
v \propto \sqrt{kT/m} = 350,000 \, \text{m/s}
$$
and so the corrections due to general relativity due to the motions of these particles will be on the order of
$$
v/c = 1 \times 10^{-3}.
$$

So for a star like the sun, the effects are probably pretty negligible, and easily swamped by our imperfect understanding of things like nuclear cross-sections, magnetic fields, and so forth.

If you want something where relativistic effects *do* matter and *are* taken into account, you have to look at things like the hydrodynamics inside a neutron star, for which $\Phi/c^2 \lesssim 1$.  But you can't really call the processes inside a neutron star "chemical" by any stretch of the imagination.  Really, almost any situation in which you're doing something that could be called "chemistry" is almost by definition non-relativistic, and to the extent that you need to include gravity, the Newtonian approximation to the full laws of general relativity will work just fine.

Comment: "Chemistry" is just driven by collisions between molecules and depends on having the proper energies to break bonds and such. So maybe the more general question is -- do the results of classical statistical mechanics hold in relativistic conditions? Are the rates or energies of collision between molecules significantly altered? Is a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution still present in equilibrium? I definitely don't know the answer to that, but would be interested in finding out!

Comment: Straumann has a derivation of Maxwell Boltzmann in curved space, if you are curious about it

Comment: @tpg2114: Similarly, the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution would not hold for a gas of relativistic particles.  Instead, it would work out to be proportional to $f(v) \, dv \propto v^2 e^{-\gamma m c^2/kT}$, where $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$ is the usual Lorentz factor.  The energy distribution would be affected, too, since the "degeneracy" (i.e., phase space volume) of the states with a given energy changes when the particles get relativistic.

Comment: That said, all of the methods of "classical" statistical mechanics should hold for relativistic particles, so long as you're careful to remember that you're using the relativistic momentum $p = \gamma m v$ and, and that the relativistic energy-momentum relationship $E^2 = p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4$ holds rather than the Newtonian versions.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert If those distributions change, then I would think chemical reactions would also be affected since they are driven by the collisions and energy contained in them.